# Jinja2 wtform checkbox is check

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Good day

I'm struggling to find a way to check in jinja2 if a wtform check box is checked.

I want to be able to make an if statement that shows when a check box is check that it will display additional input fields like:

{% if form.BooleanField == checked %}
display fields
{% endif %}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To enable one or more form fields you can use the disabled attribute of an input field or field set. Using a style sheet rule, the respective element is displayed or not.
When the user clicks the checkbox, an event listener updates the disabled attribute based on the state of the box.

An additional validator is required to validate the optional fields on the server side as well. This expects an entry in the respective field as long as the value of the referenced form field has been set.

Below is the complete code for a sample application.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (
    BooleanField,
    StringField,
    SubmitField
)
from wtforms.validators import (
    DataRequired,
    Optional
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class RequiredIf(DataRequired):
    field_flags = ('requiredif',)
    def __init__(self, other_field_name, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form[self.other_field_name]
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.other_field_name)
        if bool(other_field.data):
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)

class ExampleForm(FlaskForm):
    enabled = BooleanField(validators=[Optional()])
    field1 = StringField(validators=[RequiredIf('enabled')])
    field2 = StringField(validators=[RequiredIf('enabled')])
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ExampleForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for f in form:
            print(f'{f.name}: {f.data}')
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <style>
      fieldset[disabled], input[disabled] {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      <div>
        {{ form.enabled }}
        {{ form.enabled.label() }}
      </div>
      <fieldset name="optional-fields" {% if not form.enabled.data %}disabled{% endif %}>
        <div>
          {{ form.field1.label() }}
          {{ form.field1 }}
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ form.field2.label() }}
          {{ form.field2 }}
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        const enabledField = document.getElementById('enabled');
        const optionalFieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset[name="optional-fields"]');
        enabledField.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          optionalFieldset.disabled = !this.checked;
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```